# DATETIME MYSQL & ASP CLASSIC

Tags: datetime, asp-classic

I'm trying to pass a parameter date to a function using asp classic :i have the format datetime : 2012-02-22 00:00:00  in my database , but my parameter will contain just '2012-02-22'
so it doesnt work i receive an empty rs .

```
    <!--#include file="JSON.asp" -->
<!--#include file="JSON_UTIL_0.1.1.asp" -->

<%
function concours(datedp)
Dim sConnection, objConn , objRS 
Const adCmdText = &H0001
Const adOpenForwardOnly = 0
Const adLockReadOnly = 1
    BD_serveur = "localhost"
    BD_utilisateur = "root"
    BD_password = ""
    BD_nom = "emploipublic"
    'datedp= "2012-02-22"

    sConnection ="DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}; SERVER=" & BD_serveur & ";UID=" & BD_utilisateur & ";pwd=" & BD_password & ";database=" & BD_nom & ";option=3;"

Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open(sConnection)

Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText 
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM concours WHERE DATE(dateDepot)='"& datedp & "'"

Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

rs.Open cmd, ,adOpenForwardOnly,adLockReadOnly 

Dim jsonObject

Set jsonObject = New JSON   'JSON class is in the include file json.asp'
jsonResult =  jsonObject.toJSON(Empty, rs, False) 


Response.ContentType = "application/json" 

Response.Write jsonResult

end function 


concours("2012-02-22")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM concours WHERE dateDepot='"& datedp & "'"
```

Comment: Thank u !!it wooorks := but how can i convert the parameter datedp  to datetime ?? plz! when i test with datedp="2012-03-03" it pass but when i pass it in a paramter & call the function it return an empty rs ...

Comment: Do you have any rows in table with exactly that date? if you pass in date it takes midnight time, and not the whole day.

Comment: i tested this on mysql it works but not when i put it in my code :
    SELECT * 
FROM  `concours` 
WHERE DATE( dateDepot ) =  "2012-02-22"

Ps: Im calling my function like that : 
    concours("2012-02-22")

Comment: are you looping the recodset-object so you get the rows? show us some more code

Comment: 1) "View source" on page and make sure its "blank", json might not be visible in IE or some browsers. 2) put Response.Write(rs(0)) before the json creation and see if that prints something out. 3) something is broken in JSON class, try response.write things there too and see if something prints out

Comment: its weired it works fine , without editing any things ,i think that the problem is in the browser even if i use ctrl+r ...
thank u :)